# How to configure JMS for Cache Channel Service

Tags: content-delivery, cache-channel-service, jms

I'm now working to configure the Cache Channel Service via WebSphere <strike>MQ</strike>, specifically using WebSphere Application Server default JMS provider.  Step 1 of the SDL Live documentation states "Set up a JMS provider, such as Apache ActiveMQ, on a machine of your choosing." (see: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_5757AEB2C06D427EA5A299FAB6165052)  My question is, what are the specific steps to configure CSS with JMS?

So far I've read the following:

- Sdllive doc (http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_5757AEB2C06D427EA5A299FAB6165052)
- Quirijn's blogs (http://blog.trivident.com/category/jms-2/)
- Puff's article on how the Object Cache works (http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/analyzing_object_cache.aspx)
- Julian's article "Using SDL Tridion Object Caching with Apache Active MQ" (http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/usingsdltridionobjectcachingwithapacheactivemq.aspx)
- Serverfault question (https://serverfault.com/questions/472313/tridion-2011-sp1-hr1-cache-channel-server-setup)

Julian's article does mention that he installed Apache MQ "as per the documentation", implying that a default install is all that's required.  However, I am wondering if for WebSphere's default JMS provider there are specific settings needed or caveats to watch out for?  E.g. do we set up the JMS Point-to-Point, do we need to worry about SIDs (guessing this doesn't apply), etc.

**Addendum:** *Some answers to this question mention WebSphere MQ as per the original wording to this question.  I've modified this question from "MQ" to "default JMS provider" once getting clarity that they are separate products and that my client was using the default JMS.  However, all answers provided are still relevant.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tridion supports any MQ product that adheres to the JMS specification. Keep in mind that JMS has two modes:

1. MDB (Message Drive Bean)
2. Simple Messaging

Tridion supports both, but your specific MQ product may not support both modes (last I saw, Websphere only supported MDB by default).

Answer (score 9):

I've written a blog post addressing the configuration in a bit more detail.  The big item that needs to be considered is that an EJB Module containing an EJB spec must be provided.  The EJB spec points to a Tridion Message Driven Bean class.  Here is the link to the post:
http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/configuring-the-tridion-cache-channel-service-with-websphere-application-server-jms

Answer (score 5):

Web Sphere MQ default is non-persistent (so if an outage you loose all queue messages).. Persistent : file based (keeps in the log files on disk) --> requires to be on the "shared" FS for cluster setup or DB. When we did perf testing, MQ default(non-persistent) works out to be lot better.. Note this was WAS 6.1 and couple of years back.. So at the end we did not go with persistent and went with non persistent but with WAS node Cluster ..

When you setup the JMS factory you need to setup durable subscription model for publish/subscribe and Persistence (I think it is called Quality of Service :) ).

A nice article on Message Storage (though WAS 6.1) options.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016476&aid=1